# Is it possible to do destructuring assignment with type annotations?

Tags: rust

The overall question is how to do nested destructuring assignment with type annotations. I'm multiplying two `f32` values, but I'm unsure what will happen if the multiple overflows. Therefore, I'd like to assign them as `f64` values in order to prevent the overflow.

This example is lightly modified from Rust By Example's chapter on [structures:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/structs.html)

```rust
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

struct Rectangle {
    p1: Point,
    p2: Point,
}

fn area(rect: Rectangle) -> f64 {
    // Here's where I'd like have type annotations
    // while doing destructuring assignment:
    let Rectangle {
        p1: Point { x: x1, y: y1 },
        p2: Point { x: x2, y: y2 },
    } = rect;

    ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)).abs() as f64
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casts cannot be performed during type destructuring. This is because you cannot annotate the type that will be contained in the type you're destructuring, therefore it doesn't depend on you, and instead on the type that is being destructured. For example:

```
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}
let myOtherPoint = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
let Point {x, y} = myOtherPoint;
```

The type of `x` and `y` are defined by the type `Point`. This can, on the other hand be changed in the case of tuples and arrays:

```
fn main() {
    let [x, y, z]: [f32; 3] = [1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let (x, y, z): (usize, f32, String) = (1, 2.3, "3.4".into());
}
```

This is mostly because of type annotations needed for tuples when writing function signatures:

```
fn foo((a, b, c): (usize, f32, String)) {}
```

But this is only because tuples are not named types, per se, so there is a need to name the tuple, by annotating the type. On the other hand, `struct`s and `enum`s are named and therefore destructurable.

---

The solution to your specific issue described in the body, and not the title:
Use a separate variable with shadowing to preserve usability. Note too, that the floating point types (`f32` and `f64`) cannot be overflowed ([They have an infinity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/constant.INFINITY.html)), only integers (`[u, i][size, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]`).

```
fn area(x: Rectangle) -> f64 {
    // Here's where I'd like have type annotations
    // while doing destructuring assignment:
    let Rectangle {
        p1: Point { x: x1, y: y1 },
        p2: Point { x: x2, y: y2 },
    } = rect;

    let (x1, x2, y1, y2) = (x1 as f64, x2 as f64,
                            y1 as f64, y2 as f64);

    ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)).abs()
}
```